# SELECT column but also add AVG column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average, resultset

I'm not quite sure how to expand this query so that I can also have a `AVG(price_current)` column  ... instead of having to calculate this value within PHP once the query comes back.

```
SELECT
  listing_subtype, bedrooms, total_baths, tot_sqft_finished, price_current, latitude, longitude, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(48.639) )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-123.404) )
      + sin ( radians(48.639) )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM rets_property_resi
WHERE listing_subtype = 'Single Family Detached' AND
bedrooms >= 2 AND bedrooms <= 3 AND
total_baths >= 1 AND total_baths <= 2 AND
tot_sqft_finished >= 2000 AND tot_sqft_finished <= 2500
HAVING distance < 5
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Comment: Do you want to average all returned results and just have the same value for all returned rows, or do you want to average on some of the selected values e.g.: bathrooms and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions here:

1. You look for similar houses/homes in a given radius around a requested one. Each of those homes has a primary key in the table you are querying from. Let us call that `primKey` here.
2. Additionally, you want the average price of all returned homes which is limited to 0,25, and not the AVG of all records in the table that match you `WHERE` clause.

All returned rows will have therefore an extra field with the average price and is the same for each row.

You will have to run the same query again as a subquery. However, since you want to limit the AVG you have to run that in a subquery to calculate the correct AVG.
This is really clunky:

```
SELECT
  rets_property_resi.listing_subtype, rets_property_resi.bedrooms, rets_property_resi.total_baths, rets_property_resi.tot_sqft_finished, rets_property_resi.price_current, rets_property_resi.latitude, rets_property_resi.longitude, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(48.639) )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-123.404) )
      + sin ( radians(48.639) )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
    )
  ) AS distance, outerSubQuery.averagePrice
FROM rets_property_resi
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT innerSubQuery.primKey AS primKey, AVG(innerSubQuery.price_current) AS averagePrice
    FROM
        (SELECT
          primKey, price_current, (
            3959 * acos (
              cos ( radians(48.639) )
              * cos( radians( latitude ) )
              * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-123.404) )
              + sin ( radians(48.639) )
              * sin( radians( latitude ) )
            )
          ) AS distance
        FROM rets_property_resi
        WHERE listing_subtype = 'Single Family Detached' AND
        bedrooms >= 2 AND bedrooms <= 3 AND
        total_baths >= 1 AND total_baths <= 2 AND
        tot_sqft_finished >= 2000 AND tot_sqft_finished <= 2500
        HAVING distance < 5
        ORDER BY distance
        LIMIT 0, 25) AS innerSubQuery
    GROUP BY innerSubQuery.primKey
) AS outerSubQuery ON (outerSubQuery.primKey = rets_property_resi.primKey)

WHERE listing_subtype = 'Single Family Detached' AND
bedrooms >= 2 AND bedrooms <= 3 AND
total_baths >= 1 AND total_baths <= 2 AND
tot_sqft_finished >= 2000 AND tot_sqft_finished <= 2500
HAVING distance < 5
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

I bet there is a more elegant version of this though. You might be better off with a temporary table here or keep just calculating in code.